# Trait in return type

Tags: rust

I wrote a function which can return struct `A` or struct `B` and those structs implement a `Common` trait. I used the syntax `-> impl Common` for the return type of the function, but the code does not compile because of incompatible types:

```
trait Common {
    fn foo();
}

struct A;

impl Common for A {
    fn foo() {
        println!("Struct A");
    }
}

struct B;

impl Common for B {
    fn foo() {
        println!("Struct B");
    }
}

fn bar(param: &str) -> impl Common {
    if param == "A" {
        return A;
    } else {
        return B;
    }
}

fn main() {
    bar("A");
    bar("B");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6f24e162a6da66dd8b2583218a03071)

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:16
   |
21 | fn bar(param: &str) -> impl Common {
   |                        ----------- expected because this return type...
22 |     if param == "A" {
23 |         return A;
   |                - ...is found to be `A` here
24 |     } else {
25 |         return B;
   |                ^ expected struct `A`, found struct `B`
   |
   = note: expected type `A`
              found type `B`
```

In my first implementation I tried to use pattern matching in the function to be more idiomatic, but the error remains:

```
match param {
    "A" => A,
    "B" => B,
    _ => panic!("Invalid param"),
}
```

How can I deal with such kind of generic issue?